# If $D \subseteq X$, such that $C{l_{{\tau _2}}}\left( D \right) = X$, then $C{l_{{\tau _1}}}\left( D \right) = X$.

Tags: general-topology

I have the following problem:

> Let ${\tau _1}$ and ${\tau _2}$ be two topologies on a set $X$ such that ${\tau _1} \subseteq {\tau _2}$. $C{l_{{\tau _i}}}\left( A \right)$ is the closure if $A$ with respect to $\left( {X,{\tau _i}} \right)$ where $i = 1,2$.   Given that $C{l_{{\tau _2}}}\left( A \right) \subseteq C{l_{{\tau _1}}}\left( A \right)$ for each $A \subseteq X$; prove that if $D \subseteq X$, such that $C{l_{{\tau _2}}}\left( D \right) = X$, then $C{l_{{\tau _1}}}\left( D \right) = X$.

I have: Given that $C{l_{{\tau _2}}}\left( D \right) = X$ and $C{l_{{\tau _2}}}\left( D \right) \subseteq C{l_{{\tau _1}}}\left( D \right)$, we have $X \subseteq C{l_{{\tau _1}}}\left( D \right)$. Now how can I show that $C{l_{{\tau _1}}}\left( D \right) \subseteq X$, or is this always true?

Comment: Trivial........

Answer (score 1):

$X$ is the ambient space so trivially $\operatorname{Cl}_{\tau_1}(D) \subseteq X$. So $\operatorname{Cl}_{\tau_1}(D) = X$.

In words: if a set is dense in a finer topology, it's already dense in the current topology.